# multiple requests in one URLusing expressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express with Node and I have a requirement in which the user can request the URL as: `http://myhost/api/add?mid="mid01"/userID`
and I tried this

```
app.get('/api/:myMedia/:id', function (req, res){
    ...
})
```

and tried these `req.query` for getting `mid01` and it didn't work.
I want to have `req.params.id` and `req.query` together. How can I handle this?

Comment: shouldn't that be `/api/add/themedia/theid?mid=mid01`? Why would the queryparam come before the other params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement really is `http://myhost/api/add?mid="mid01"/userID`, it might be a good idea to change that requirement, because it seems really not the right way to do something

But if you really want to do that you should declare your route like `app.get('/api/add', ...)`

Then with `req.query.mid` you can get your query value which is `"mid01"/userID`

Finaly it's up to you to parse that query value to do what you want

---

But you should not use URL like that, if possible try to use URL in a more standard way, `http://myhost/api/add/userID?mid=mid01` or `http://myhost/api/add?mid=mid01&path=/userID`

Answer (score 0):

To chain requests, use &. http://myhost/api/add?foo1="bar1"&foo2="bar2". This way both of the queries will show up.